# Which is the block/template file for product edit page in Admin of Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3

I would like to know which is the block/template file for product edit page in Admin of Magento 2. Using template hints to find this out displays a path to template that is not found where it shows it is.

Comment: you are view this path module-catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit i think this path

Comment: @Mohit Patel, okay. will check it out

Comment: @Mohit Patel, I would accept it as answer if you could convert your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are view this path may be help you this path `module-catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit`

Check

[image]

Thanks.